# Freepbx sipnet дает совершить один оригинальный звонок

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

При совершении звонка на новый номер (на который не звонили ранее) - звонок проходит успешно. Сразу же звоню на этот номер и получаю сообщение "...number is not in service". и дальнейшние попытки безуспешны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот лог, где я звоню с 3004 - первый звонок успешный, сразу за ним - нет:
[log](https://wdfiles.ru/1rD48)